Configuring Node.js Project for Public Asset Access on Vercel
I'm working on a Node.js application deployed on Vercel
here is my vercel.json:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": { "includeFiles": ["dist/**"] }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/server.js"
    }
  ],
  "public": true
}

I'd like to ensure my public assets (images) are accessible from their URLs.
Here is my project structure:

Here is my server.js:
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import routes from './routes';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port: Number = 3000;

const corsOption = {
  origin: process.env.BASE_URL,
};

app.use(cors(corsOption));

app.use(express.json({ limit: '20mb' }));

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

app.use('/api', routes);

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  return res.send('Server running');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on ' + port);
});


